# What is the name of this "co-direct sum" of vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, banach-spaces, dual-spaces, direct-sum

Suppose that we have a finite-dimensional real vector space $V$ and its dual space of linear functionals $V^*$.

Now, suppose that $S$ and $T$ are subspaces of $V$. For now we will require $S$ and $T$ to have trivial intersection, but later we will look at general subspaces.

As these are also vector spaces, we can look at the dual spaces $S^*$ and $T^*$. As $S$ and $T$ are *subspaces* of $V$, $S^*$ and $T^*$ can be naturally viewed as *quotient spaces* of $V^*$. In particular, we have that $S^* = V^*/\text{ann}(S)$, where $\text{ann}(S)$ is the annihilator of $S$. This equality is in the sense that for any  $f$ in $V^*$ and any $s$ in $S$, we have that $\langle f, s\rangle = \langle f+g, s \rangle$, so that we can identify linear functionals on $S$ with entire cosets of $V$.

**Now, the terminology question**:

- The space $S \oplus T$ is the "direct sum" of $S$ and $T$.
- The dual space of $(S \oplus T)^*$ is the "______________" of $S^*$ and $T^*$??

What is the __________? Is there a name for this "co-direct sum?"

If $S$ and $T$ have trivial intersection, this is simply a different quotient space whose kernel is the intersection of the kernels of $S^*$ and $T^*$ in $V^*$.

If they *don't* have trivial intersection then this is very interesting. For instance, suppose we have that $S = T = V$. Then we have that $S\oplus T = V\oplus V$, and in *this* situation we get that the "co-direct sum" is also equal to the direct sum $S^* \oplus T^* = V^* \oplus V$.

What is the name for this?

Comment: One can view $S\oplus T$ as the pushout of $S$ and $T$ relative to the inclusions into $V$ when they have trivial intersection. In that light, I would expect $(S\oplus T)^*$ to be the pullback of $S^*$ and $T^*$. When $S$ and $T$ don't have trivial intersection we don't usually use $\oplus$, though, lest it be confused with the *internal* direct sum. Instead, you seem to be taking it to be  the so-called "external direct sum", which is really $S\times T$. I would instead have taken $S+T$, which is still the pushout.

Comment: Thank you @ArturoMagidin - what is the thing you are calling $S + T$ above?

Comment: $S+T$ is the join of $S$ and $T$ in $V$: the smallest subspace that contains both $S$ and $T$. As a set, it consists of $\{s+t\mid s\in S, t\in T\}$. Traditionally, the symbol $\oplus$ is used for $S+T$ when in addition we have $S\cap T=\{\mathbf{0}\}$.